# MLE Estimator of a uniform distribution with two parameters.

Tags: probability

I'm currently stuck on a problem to find the maximum likelihood estimator of a uniform distribution. The problem is the following:

"For the uniform distribution unif $[2 \theta_{1} \theta_{2},\theta_{1}^2+\theta_{2}^2]$ find the estimators for $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ where ($\theta_{2}>\theta_{1}>0$) using the Maximum Likelihood estimator."

I've seen many question about the topic. so far I've computed the likelihood and the log likelihood function:

$Likelihood function = (\theta_{1}+\theta_{2})^{-2}$

$LogLikelihoodfunction = -2log(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2})$

from this how should I continue?

I'm really looking forward to some help!  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your likelihood (and thus log-likelihood) is incorrect.

The density of a single observation from this distribution is $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{(\theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2) - 2\theta_1\theta_2} \mathbb{1}(2\theta_1 \theta_2 \le x \le \theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2).$$  The denominator is the square of the **difference**:  $$f_X(x) = (\theta_2 - \theta_1)^{-2} \mathbb{1}(2\theta_1 \theta_2 \le x \le \theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2).$$  Therefore, the likelihood given a sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is $$\mathcal{L}(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid \boldsymbol x) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_X(x_i) = (\theta_2 - \theta_1)^{-2n} \mathbb{1}(2\theta_1 \theta_2 \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le \theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2).$$  The log-likelihood is $$\ell(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid \boldsymbol x) = -2n \log (\theta_2 - \theta_1), \quad 2\theta_1 \theta_2 \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le \theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2.$$  The partial derivatives with respect to $\theta_1, \theta_2$ are $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_1} = \frac{2n}{\theta_2 - \theta_1}, \quad \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_2} = \frac{2n}{\theta_1 - \theta_2}.$$  Note that for any choice of $\theta_1, \theta_2$ such that $\theta_2 > \theta_1 > 0$, neither partial derivative has a critical point.  Therefore, the log-likelihood is maximized for a choice of $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ that **minimizes** the difference $\theta_2 - \theta_1$ subject to the constraint $$2\theta_1 \theta_2 \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le \theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2.$$  Consider these conditions separately:  $$2\theta_1 \theta_2 = x_{(1)}$$ describes a hyperbola in the $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ coordinate system, and similarly, $$\theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2 = x_{(n)}$$ describes a circle of radius $\sqrt{x_{(n)}}$.  The region of the plane that satisfies both inequalities is therefore a region in the first quadrant such that $\theta_1 < \theta_2$, **below** the hyperbola and **above** (outside) the circle.  Over this region, it is clear that the point with minimal $\theta_2 - \theta_1$ is located at the intersection of the two curves.  Therefore, the MLE is the solution to the system $$2\theta_1 \theta_2 = x_{(1)}, \quad \theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2 = x_{(n)}.$$  Note: the above is not a completely rigorous argument; it is only intended as motivation.  You will need to prove it rigorously using other methods.  I leave it to you to explicitly solve this system in terms of the minimum and maximum order statistics and fill in the details of the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and pointing out my mistake. Your answer was really clear and helped me a lot. However, when you say that the answer to the MLE is the solution to the system 
$2\theta_{1}\theta_{2}=x_{(1)}$,$ \theta_{1}^2+\theta_{2}^2 =x_{(n)}$
How am I supposed to conclude since my sample is not defined?

Comment: In general, **any** estimator will be some function of the sample.  Your MLE for this problem is a function of the min and max values observed in your sample.  That you don't know what these are *a priori* does not preclude you from furnishing a formula that tells you what the MLE should be once you have observed the sample.  For example, if I observe the sample $$(x_1, \ldots, x_5) = (3, 4, 1, 11, 7),$$ I immediately know $x_{(1)} = 1$ and $x_{(5)} = 11$, and my MLE will be the solution to $2\theta_1\theta_2 = 1$, $\theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2 = 11$ satisfying $\theta_1 < \theta_2$.